# Bypass forgery protection for trusted IP addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to have Ruby on Rails forgery protection turned on, but ignore token mismatches from trusted IP addresses?

Basically I want the benefits of forgery protection but would like to allow requests from a trusted machine with a fixed IP address to be able to post into my controller without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the forgery protection for specific actions. The specific actions could be performed for whitelisted IPs only, perhaps in conjunction with a `before_filter` or related methods.

**References**

- [Ruby on Rails API Request Forgery Protection documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html).
- [`before_filter` and related methods](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/before_filter).